# Linked List setting value - int object has no attribute 'value' error

Tags: python, linked-list, integer, attributes

```
class Node:
#creates node
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None 
    

class LinkedList : 
    def __init__(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value) #creates node
        self.head = new_node #
        self.tail = new_node
        self.length = 1 #optional, I just put it for my understanding
    
    def print_list(self) : 
        temp = self.head #see the first node
        while temp is not None :
            print(temp.value)
            temp = temp.next 

    def append(self, value): 
        new_node = Node(value) 
        if self.head is None : 
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        else :
            self.tail.next = new_node 
            self.tail = new_node
        self.length += 1 

    def get(self, index): 
        if index < 0 or index>= self.length : #when list number is out of range 
            return None 
        temp = self.head
        for _ in range(index) :   
            temp = temp.next 
            return temp.value 

    def set_value(self, index, value ): #sets the value by getting index number and the value 
        temp = self.get(index)
        if temp is not None : # passes the list range test. make sure it is in range
            temp.value = value #THE ERROR occurs here. 
            return True 
        return False 


my_LL = LinkedList(11)
my_LL.append(3)
my_LL.append(23)
my_LL.append(7)
my_LL.set_value(1,4)
print_list()
```

I'm doing linked list using python now.

The set value takes in the index number of the linked list and a desired value that changes the value of the index number to the desired value. for example: set_value(1, 4) would change 11->3->23->7 to 11->4->23->7 .

I tried to run the program, but got "**int object has no attribute 'value' " error.**

**I can't figure out why the error occured and how to fix it.**

Comment: `LinkedList.get` returns a value, not the node that contains the value, so `temp` is not a `Node` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to access the value attribute of the get result, which is an integer rather than a Node object, using the set value method.

You should change the 'get' method to this:

```
def get(self, index):  
        if index < 0 or index >= self.length: #when list number is out of range
            return None 
        temp = self.head
        for _ in range(index) :   
            temp = temp.next 
        return temp
```

Change the 'set_value' method to this:

```
def set_value(self, index, value ): #sets the value by getting index number and the value 
        temp = self.get(index)
        if temp is not None : # passes the list range test. make sure it is in range
            temp.value = value 
            return True 
        return False
```

And you should also add my_LL. before print_list()
like this:

```
my_LL.print_list()
```

Now the output should look like this:

11

4

23

7